# ViewExpiredException in Firefox and IE after migrating to Jboss 7.0 AS

Tags: jsf, jboss, richfaces

We have JSF 2.0 Richfaces 4.0 application working perfectly fine on Jboss 6.0 and we are trying migrate it to Jboss 7.0 AS.

We are experiencing ViewExpiredException in firefox and IE for any link we click on the page. In google chrome it is working fine. Note sure what is the problem. I don't have any clue how to debug this.

Please let me know anybody experienced similar issue.

Thanks,
Mahesh

Answer (score 1):

Mahesh you are experiencing https://issues.jboss.org/browse/AS7-1283

Pass -Dorg.apache.tomcat.util.http.ServerCookie.FWD_SLASH_IS_SEPARATOR=false when you start AS 7 or add the property to your config by following https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS7/Admin+Guide#AdminGuide-SystemProperties